# AttributeError thrown at build time but not in preview mode

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to write unstructured data to file in a transform. Running the transform in preview mode is successful, but building the dataset is not. Specifically, it seems like the `FileSystem` object has a `files_dir` attribute only when previewing and not at build time.

```py
@transform(
    data_input = Input("..."),
    data_output= Output("..."),
)
def transform(data_input, data_output):
    for file_status in data_input.filesystem().files('*.<file_ending>').collect():
         data= PreProcessor(f"{data_input.filesystem().files_dir}/{file_status.path}")

         # Throws "AttributeError: 'FileSystem' object has no attribute 'files_dir'"
         data.write(f"{data_output.filesystem().files_dir}/transformed_file")
```

How can I resolve this issue? Why is the `files_dir` attribute not set at build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because `files_dir` at runtime during preview mode. Instead, I used the `hadoop_path` attribute, which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Preview and build use different data volumes, which means that you may have slightly different results. Preview uses a subset of files, or a subset of data (1000 rows only), this means that your code in preview may not hit edge cases if they are not present in the specific subset that was chosen to be computed.

Here's some logic where I was getting all headers from a cluster of CSVs as an example. This works in both preview and build time.

```py
@transform(
    out=Output("out..."),
    raw=Input("in..."),
)
def extract_all_headers(raw, out, ctx):
    rows = []
    headers = {}
    files = raw.filesystem().ls("*.csv")
    for csv in files:
        with raw.filesystem().open(csv.path) as f:
            header = f.readline()
            for name in header.split(","):
                name = name.strip()
                if name not in headers:
                    headers[name] = True
                    rows.append([name])
            f.close()

    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("column_name", T.StringType(), True)])
    
    out.write_dataframe(ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(rows, schema=schema))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't think this answers the question. How does working on a subset of the data mean that the ``files_dir`` attribute should not be set?

Comment: They run in different spark environments with different setups (sorry forgot to mention that).

Comment: I still don't understand why that means that the ``files_dir`` attribute should be set in one but not the other environment, sorry.

Comment: Sorry @stn53 I don't want to go to through the implementation details of preview in a public Q&A system